# Cannot use rootReducer in redux , react/typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, store

I'm learning redux with react/typescript. Everything was fine until I use more than 1 reducer.
At first, I created the store like this:

```js
import { AuthReducer } from './reducers/AuthReducer' 
const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore (AuthReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
export default store
```

But when I try to use `rootReducer` the data I logged from store is undefined.

```js
import { AuthReducer } from './reducers/AuthReducer' 

const middleware = [thunk]; 
const rootReducer=combineReducers({
  AuthReducer, 
  CartReducer 
})

const store = createStore (rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
export default store
```

Comment: how do you use state form store

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't include code or error messages as screenshots or images. It makes it more difficult to help you. Take the time to include a [mcve] as formatted text within your question (I edited your question in this instance).

Comment: Agreed with @Viet, now that you're combining reducers everything that was in `state` will now be in `state.AuthReducer`, etc...

Comment: i get state like this : const userState:UserState = useSelector((state:UserState) => state)

Comment: Oh jesus christ , thank you very much. I've been stucked on this for 2 days. And I solved it thanks to your question @Viet. I though the problem is the store but it acctully comes from the way I use state .

Comment: Generally please be aware that you are writing an old style of Redux and thus probably TypeScript patterns that we now consider antipatterns. Please stick to the official Redux tutorial to learn using Redux: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import reducers from '../Reducers'
//this is all your reducers that  are combined

const middleWare = [ thunk ]

const store = createStore (
    reducers,
    undefined,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(...middleWare)
    )
)
export default store;
```